# bootstrap のmodal がiOSの端末でスクロール出来ない

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap3でmodal内で検索できるような仕組みを作りました。テキストボックスの内容をAjaxでPHPに送信して結果をJsonで受け取ります。その内容をmodal内で表示するのですが、結果が多くなったときにスクロール（スワイプ）が出来ない状況になりました。どうもこの現象がiOSの端末のみで発生しているようです。
この解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃったら教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

モーダルということで`position: fixed;`などを指定している可能性は高いと思いますし、
こちらのページを参考にスクロールしたい対象をさらにdivで囲むなどしてみてはいかがでしょうか？

[iOS Safari で絶対位置指定された要素のスクロールが出来ない件](http://qiita.com/chocolamint/items/67d25933880404c93db0)